# Passing variable value from state to another widget

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

I am struggling with one simple case and it would be lovely if someone could help here.

Let's say that I have some `stateful widget`. In its state I define a variable (might be of any type) and this variable is later changed through `setState()` method, where I dynamically assign its value based on some certain criteria. Evertyhing until this point is conducted within one class.

What if I would like to access the value of this variable from another class (totally different `page`) and if its value changes, rebuild it? Could you please also give me some examples?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Balaji is correct with his answer below that provider is one example of how you can do this. But you are touching on the rather large topic of State Management and there are multiple options available to you for this. A link to a list of state management approaches in Flutter can be found here: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I perhaps did not express myself crealy. Let's say I have some stateful widget named LoginPage and then in _LoginPageState I define a bool variable that is changed within the setstate based on crateria. Then if this value changes I would like to pass the value to another page e.g. main page? Could you show me the sample code pls?

Comment: @NetworkingFreak, we got the question.But we have only have state management as an option to pass the data around.Also you can try InheritedWidget from flutter

Answer (score 3):

That's exactly why State MANAGEMENT exists.
To manage your state through your app.
There are many different options to follow
See:
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I perhaps did not express myself crealy. Let's say I have some stateful widget named LoginPage and then in _LoginPageState I define a bool variable that is changed within the setstate based on crateria. Then if this value changes I would like to pass the value to another page e.g. main page? Could you show me the sample code pls?

Comment: I want to pass value from state to another class not to the state.

Comment: In this case you can inject your variables to the next class or page using its constructor BUT what if you want to pass this variable to a parent class or Widget, thats why you need to use a state management solution exactly as explained in @balaji example notice that he define the variable in a neutral class or in a better word a state holding class using provider and inheritedWidget then you can access this variable anywhere from your widget tree.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `provider` package in that case.
In `yaml` file add,
`provider: ^4.3.2+4`

```
class HomeApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeAppState createState() => _HomeAppState();
}

class _HomeAppState extends State<HomeApp> {
  Counter _counterProvider;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _counterProvider = Provider.of(context, listen: false);
  }

  void updateCounter() {
    _counterProvider.setCount();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Counter _counterProvider = Provider.of(context);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Container(
              child: Text(
                _counterProvider.count.toString(),
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 22,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: updateCounter,
              child: Text('Click'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
// class for storing data(Counter.dart)
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Counter extends ChangeNotifier { // create a common file for data
  int _count = 0;

  int get count => _count;

  void setCount() {
    _count++;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I perhaps did not express myself crealy. Let's say I have some stateful widget named LoginPage and then in _LoginPageState I define a bool variable that is changed within the setstate based on crateria. Then if this value changes I would like to pass the value to another page e.g. main page? Could you show me the sample code pls?

Comment: As for now, I try to add "with ChangeNotifier" to _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage>. Then to the setState function I add "notifyListeners();" when value changes and I dont know how to just pass this one variable to another widget afterwards.